# PHP MYSQL Union Query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

Im new to mysql queries and im having trouble obtaining the data structure I want.  Im hoping one of you guys can help.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE post_id IN (SELECT id from wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'product')
```

Which simply grabs all the data from Table 2 that has the same id as the product in Table 1.  The problem is that the results return as:

```
{meta_id: "37230", post_id: "2549", meta_key: "total_sales", meta_value: "0"}
{meta_id: "37231", post_id: "2549", meta_key: "_virtual", meta_value: "no"}
{meta_id: "37232", post_id: "2549", meta_key: "_tax_status", meta_value: "taxable"}
{meta_id: "37233", post_id: "2549", meta_key: "_visibility", meta_value: "visible"}
{meta_id: "37234", post_id: "2549", meta_key: "_featured", meta_value: "no"}
{meta_id: "37235", post_id: "2549", meta_key: "_weight", meta_value: "0.50"}
{meta_id: "37236", post_id: "2549", meta_key: "_sku", meta_value: "HCS-DGMP"}
{meta_id: "37237", post_id: "2549", meta_key: "_product_attributes", meta_value: "a:0:{}"}
{meta_id: "37238", post_id: "2549", meta_key: "_regular_price", meta_value: "18.99"}
{meta_id: "37239", post_id: "2549", meta_key: "_sale_price", meta_value: ""}
```

As you can see, they all have the same post ID, but are returned in seperate objects.  How can I modify my query above so that all of that returns in one object?  I'll also be removing the `meta_id` as it is useless.

Comment: Loop through all the arrays, and create a new array whose keys are the `meta_key` and values are the `meta_value`

Comment: @Barmar Hmm, thats true.  Is there no way to adjust the query to do that? Or would your suggestion be more performant?

Comment: What do you mean "separate objects"?  Result sets consist of *rows* not *objects*.

Comment: @GordonLinoff depending on settings or fetch mode, PHP can return rows as objects with columns as object attributes. However - This part (fetching the result in PHP) is missing in this answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since *MySQL 5.7.22* you can use [`JSON_OBJECTAGG(key, value)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-objectagg):

```sql
SELECT post_id, JSON_OBJECTAGG(meta_key, meta_value) AS meta_data
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE post_id IN (SELECT id from wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'product')
GROUP by post_id
```

This will return `meta_data` as JSON_OBJECT with `key: value` pairs:

```
post_id | meta_data
   2549 | {"_sku": "HCS-DGMP", "_weight": "0.50", "_virtual": "no", "_featured": "no", "_sale_price": null, "_tax_status": "taxable", "_visibility": "visible", "total_sales": "0", "_regular_price": "18.99", "_product_attributes": "a:0:{}"}
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bxZoYUsbxWCSpVizeWe2E7/0)

If your server doesn't support `JSON_OBJECTAGG()`, I would use a PHP solution:

```php
$postIds = array_unique(array_column($dbResult, 'post_id'));

$posts = [];
foreach ($postIds as $id) {
    $posts[$id] = (object)['id' => $id];
}

foreach ($dbResult as $row) {
    $posts[$row->post_id]->{$row->meta_key} = $row->meta_value;
}

echo json_encode(array_values($posts), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "id": "2549",
        "total_sales": "0",
        "_virtual": "no",
        "_tax_status": "taxable",
        "_visibility": "visible",
        "_featured": "no",
        "_weight": "0.50",
        "_sku": "HCS-DGMP",
        "_product_attributes": "a:0:{}",
        "_regular_price": "18.99",
        "_sale_price": ""
    }
]
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/LUT70189)

As long as you are not processing thousands of rows, I wouldn't worry about performance.

Comment: Oh man that pretty neat, hate been stuck on 5.6 that `JSON_OBJECTAGG` seems useful

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina With 5.6 you can [emulate](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2MfwAugw1W6bnhkgPmJiXu/0) it with `GROUP_CONCAT`. But the values may not contain double-quotes or NULLs. I would write a PHP solution, which wouldn't be so terribly complex.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but this just looks so much better. Yeah that wouldn't be too bad, but this IMO would be cleaner. Just need an `json_ecode`, `array_combine` and two `array_columns`, but then you'd have to fetch all that extra data D:

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina The extra data is just one INT (post_id) per key-value pair - So not so much. I might even prefer a PHP solution with newer MySQL versions, because it's more flexible.